# Refresh Textured Ceiling with really thin mud?

Tags: drywall, ceiling

I am thinking about thinning down white mud (USG white topping mud) and covering up discolored textured ceiling. Not popcorn. How thin is too thin for white mud? Any tips, application methods?

Details: Doing a kitchen renovation, removed a wall, patched the drywall, and now need to match the color and texture for the whole new large ceiling. The textured ceiling is the same style throughout and I can match decently well (for a DIY'er) the crows foot, stomped, firework texture. We don't love it, but don't hate it enough to scrape it all off.

Here's the problem: The ceiling above the old stove location is discolored yellow over the years and it would be a pain to try to color match the transition. My thought is to mix up some really thin white topping mud and use a roller to essentially "paint" over the discoloration with the thin mud and get a uniform color on the whole ceiling. There's too much to scrape and Skim coat and it'll ruin my timeline for a good kitchen for thanksgiving. Don't want to paint in case I need to scrape it all off one day. Advice?

Comment: Why would you not just paint the whole ceiling? That seems like less work and would result in a better outcome. You're unlikely to get the same color and sheen with your plan.

Comment: Isherwood, I may end up doing that. It will be a huge headache down the road if we want to remove the texture, which is possible. I’m trying some test areas to see if it’ll work.

Comment: I can't be specific, but over-watering joint compound will result in microcracks when it dries due to severe shrink. You should just do some tests.

Comment: Don't know how removing an additional layer of mud is more/less of a hassle than removing the existing layer and another coat of paint...

Comment: Why would you have to scrape off interior paint? Just paint over it when you want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

So far so good after about 45 mins, I wish I would have kept track of the water:mud ratio, but the thickness was runny pancake batter. I’ll keep seeing how it drys throughout the day.

Update: The test area held up great with no cracks or other blemishes and we finally got the time to finish the rest of the ceiling. Worked well. The consistency was runny pancake batter that ran off a knife in ribbons. Applied with a 3/8 nap roller, Looks almost transparent when applied, but dries to a uniform coat. [image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Tyler, welcome to the site.  Please note this works differently to other sites.  It is not a discussion forum.  Consequently your answer is not an answer until you have finished and can stipulate what the ratio should be.